# Still error! No self service registration in Okta Directory, alraedy set profile enrollment, trusted cors, clientID and issuer

Tags: angular, angularjs, okta, angular-fullstack, okta-signin-widget

I am not able to find the SSR on the okta admin directory.

I have enable the profile enrollment. I have set the trusted cors, put in issuer and clientID.
But my angular still showing error in the browser console GET https://dev-61621026.okta.com/api/v1/registration/form

Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you might be using Okta Identity Engine (OIE) instead of Classic. For OIE, self-service registration is not supported. So if the widget is configured for the classic pipeline in an OIE Org and you enabled, `features.registration`, you will get an error when clicking sign-up because /form is not an endpoint for OIE. You need to use profile enrollment instead.

https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/ie-limitations/main/#self-service-registration

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, I got it dy. Wish you have a wonderful day. Thanks again.